# Answer/comment vanished?

Tags: support, notifications

I have a question about my Server Fault post: [Using Hamachi to link domain controllers at multiple sites](https://serverfault.com/questions/819750/using-hamachi-to-link-domain-controllers-at-multiple-sites)

Yesterday I received a notification on my phone from the StackExchange app that there was an answer/comment on my question saying something like

> It is possible using Hamachi...

However, when I opened the site I saw that there is nothing. What's more interesting is that is that there is nothing in my inbox - like nothing happened. I'm really confused now - what happened?

I'm new to StackExchnage so I might be missing something obvious....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone posted an answer that basically said "Yes it's possible here is a youtube video that explains how to install Hamachi".
The answer was later deleted by a moderator.

Comment: Ah ok, that explains it.... Thanks!

Comment: As (one of?) the people who flagged that reply as very low quality, you really didn't miss anything @Xymanek I promise you, it was very basic "congratulations on managing to navigate to the hamachi website without setting fire to your computer somehow, now here's how to double-click the installer" stuff.

Comment: Too bad, I was hoping so much for answer.... Thanks for info @RobMoir